# Actionlint issue with Github actions

Tags: shell, github, yaml, github-actions, shellcheck

I'm trying to use **reviewdog/action-actionlint:v1.18.2** and I'm getting this error:

```
 shellcheck reported issue in this script: SC2046:warning:1:35: Quote this to prevent word splitting [shellcheck]
```

at this line:

```sh
run: |
          echo "COMMIT_COUNT=$(git rev-list $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --count)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

what should I do ?

Comment: Probably `"$GITHUB_ENV"`, with double quotes.

Comment: Oh, and double quote the inner command substitution.

Comment: Paste the line into https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see where exactly it wants you to change things.

Comment: I followed the suggestions created by shellcheck.net and it worked! Thanks

Comment: The 1:35 means line 1 of the run section and column 35 is where the problem it is complaining about lies. The columns start even with the multiline "run" section.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that it wants you to replace this:

```
echo "COMMIT_COUNT=$(git rev-list $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --count)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

With this:

```
echo "COMMIT_COUNT=$(git rev-list "$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)"..HEAD --count)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

This is so that if the output of `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` contains a space for some reason, a space will end up in the argument to `git rev-list`, instead of two arguments being passed. I don't think the output of that particular command will ever actually contain a space, but it's a good practice to quote anyway unless you actually want splitting to happen.